# EF code first - add inverse propterty with optional element

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following classes

```
    public class Order  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string From { get; set; }

    public int? TreatGuestEntryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TreatGuestEntryID")]
    public TreatedGuestEntry TreatGuestEntry { get; set; }
```

...

```
public class TreatedGuestEntry  {
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
[MaxLength(200)]
public string Company { get; set; }
public string TypeOfTreat { get; set; }
```

This works as expected - in my Orders table it creates the foreign key.

Now I want to add an inverse property in TreatedGuestEntry for the order.
The best (at least somehow working) result I get when I add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TreatedGuestEntry>()
.HasOptional(a => a.Order)
.WithOptionalDependent(a => a.TreatGuestEntry)
.Map(a=>a.MapKey("TreatGuestEntryID"));
```

and further rename the key of TreatedGuestEntry to TreatGuestEntryID.
But I get no relation in the database and also TreatGuestEntryID in the table Order is no longer a key (FK).

My approach in simple words:
In my Order I want an optional TreatedGuestEntry (and I need access to the foreign key) - and further in the related TreatedGuestEntry I want to access the Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the FK `TreatGuestEntryID` is not a PK, it means that it is a 1:n relationship. So, you have to put a `Collection` of `Order` on the other side:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string From { get; set; }

    public int? TreatGuestEntryID { get; set; }

    public TreatedGuestEntry TreatGuestEntry { get; set; }
}

public class TreatedGuestEntry
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string TypeOfTreat { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .HasOptional(i => i.TreatGuestEntry)
    .WithMany(i => i.Orders)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.TreatGuestEntryID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Generated Migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Orders",
    c => new
        {
            ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
            From = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
            TreatGuestEntryID = c.Int(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.TreatedGuestEntries", t => t.TreatGuestEntryID)
    .Index(t => t.TreatGuestEntryID);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.TreatedGuestEntries",
    c => new
        {
            ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Company = c.String(maxLength: 200),
            TypeOfTreat = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
```

Comment: Hi Fabio, I'm afraid you are right. - Is it also not possible to overcome this with making TreatGuestEntryID since it is (must be) nullable. Thanks a lot